# What is the default time for the jQuery clip effect?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Simple question, but can't seem to find an answer via Google searching and elsewhere. I checked a couple of places, such as:

[jQuery UI API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/clip-effect/)

[jQuery site](https://plugins.jquery.com/ui.effect-clip/)

[TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/effect-clip.htm)

[the source code itself](http:////code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js)

and I cannot find the default time. I assume it is 400 ms because the animate() method is called to produce the clip effect, and the default time for animate() is 400 ms. Does anyone know if this is correct? Thanks!

Comment: Ya the default duration is 400ms `because the animate() method is called to produce the clip effect`  From jQuery source: `jQuery.fx.speeds = {
 slow: 600,
 fast: 200,
 // Default speed
 _default: 400
};`

Comment: i also think its 400ms only https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/effect-clip.js if you see the code internally its calling jquery's animate only

Comment: OK...thanks. For as much as I like the jQuery UI, the docs have some missing info.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already in the comments, its 400ms. Heres a way to calculate the duration of timeouts, intervals, animations, effects,...:

```
var starting = new Date().getTime();
setTimeout(function () { //or any animation,effect,...
  var ending = new Date().getTime();
  alert(ending-starting); // ~500
}, 500);
```